# Why was the question about whether the West ever influenced Indian elections closed?

Tags: discussion

This

[Did the West influence Indian elections?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/66145/did-the-west-influence-indian-elections)

seemed like a perfectly fine question to me.

Given the history of US interventions in South America, one might suspect that the US may have intervened in the elections of friendly countries.

After all, we know from a story by the BBC a few years ago that the US was bugging the phones of their allies in the West, including the Chancellor of Germany, Angela Merkel, from 2002–2013!

Given those, one might suspect similar interventions in other friendly countries, such as India …

Comment: I have edited the question to add some sources on why I think such influence exists in elections process and decision making although the question is still closed

Comment: @James The question reads like it was written to push an opinion that "Yes, the US did interfere in Indian elections". The edits make it worse ("Proofs that some election influence exists"). A more neutrally phrased question, e.g. "[Source xyz] claims the US interfered in the Indian election of [abc year], is there evidence to support this claim?" would probably have been better received.

Comment: @Semaphore: I think we should distinguish between pushing an opinion and researching a possibility. I'd say it is the latter in this case. I've already said elsewhere that the question could be better phrased, but not everyone knows how to write well. Whilst some who do, are actually pushing an opinion - see rhetoric and polemic.

Comment: @MoziburUllah There's a difference between background research, and thinking they have proof for an answer. In the latter case, the preferred practice is to write it as an answer to a neutrally phrased question.

Comment: *seemed like a perfectly fine question to me* - Which is probably why *you* are not among the ones that casted close votes. :-)